# custom filter expression for a specific part of a string in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

I want to make a custom filter that only displays the 12th character - 16th character of the string

I made this filters.js file  :

```
angular.module('customFilters', []).filter('specificDate', function() {
  return function(input) {

  };
});
```

The things i want to put the expression on are all the options from this select item :

```
<select ng-model="selectedSong" ng-options="song as song.played_at for song in songs.tracks"></select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In angular you can format date types. In you case you can use like this:

```
<p>{{song.playedAt | date:'hh:mm'}}<p/>
```

[AngularJS Date Filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

Comment: cool but how can I put the filter in my dropdownlist ? because I only see ng-model and ng-options now and it doesn't seem to fit in those

Comment: And this does solve the date problem but I also wanted to use these filters on other things (not dates) where i use other parts of a string.

Comment: For the date problem, you can use `ng-options="song as (song.played_at | date: 'hh:mm') for song in songs.tracks"`. But if you want to use in other strings, you can use `substring` like `song.played.substring(11, 15)`